# Why can't I reposition my desktop icons in Windows 8.1 Pro?

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, desktop, icons

I've tried everything that I can think of. When I try to drag and drop a desktop icon, the cursor turns to a slashed-out circle and won't let me move the icon. I can't drag them into folders or anything. The only way to reposition any icon on my desktop is to completely delete it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get the same issues after [starting Windows in Safe Mode](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-startup-settings-including-safe-mode)? Did you try [performing a clean boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135/en-us) already?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Uninstall Fences and reboot ( if it's installed)

See comments in link below for additional solutions:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-desktop/unable-to-move-desktop-icon-after-81-update/2f21554c-6a79-4952-a1dc-5e5da61c6095